# How to catch and return (or print) an exception in an ORACLE PL/SQL create or replace stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a PL/SQL stored procedure inside which I want to run several updates, then capture any exceptions and return them in an out parameter. For simplicitys sake in the code block below I am simply outputting the exception code and error message to the console. However, the code block below does not work (I am experiencing a "found / expecting" syntax error)

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DBP.TESTING_SP AS 
    DECLARE
    v_code  NUMBER;
    v_errm  VARCHAR2(64);
    BEGIN
    UPDATE PS_NE_PHONE_TBL SET NE_PHONE_TYPE = 'TEST' WHERE NEMPLID_TBL = 'N14924';

    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    v_code := SQLCODE;
    v_errm := SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1, 64);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_code || ' ' || v_errm);
    END TESTING_SP;
    /
```

What is the correct syntax for what I am trying to do?

I read on one forum

> "When using the Create or Replace syntax, you can not use Declare. Declare is only for anonymous blocks that are not named. So either remove line 1 and create an anonymous block, or remove line 2 and create a named procedure."

but I'm not sure how to create an anonymous block or create a named procedure to accomplish what I want to do (if that, indeed, is the 'solution'). Could somebody lend a hand?

Comment: Unless you are are doing something useful with the exception information, there is no need to catch it.  The best way to pass exception information to the calling function is to do nothing, and let the exception naturally raise.  This uses less code and preserves the real line number of the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove the DECLARE statement.

Comment: awesome, thanks! could you explain why I dont need the declare statement in this case (where as all the examples I saw have the declare statement)?

Comment: The DECLARE is for an anonymous block. If you are creating a procedure that can be called by name, use the CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE syntax. An anonymous block is run each time you want the procedure executed.